# How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?

Tags: c, operating-system, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I need my code to do different things based on the operating system on which it gets compiled. I'm looking for something like this:

```
#ifdef OSisWindows
// do Windows-specific stuff
#else
// do Unix-specific stuff
#endif
```

Is there a way to do this? Is there a better way to do the same thing?

Comment: @Cory Klein: No-no. this question has been asked years-before

Comment: This is about `C` not `C++`

Comment: [How to detect reliably Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, Windows in C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5919996/995714), [Detect Windows or Linux in C, C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8666378/995714)

Comment: @CoryKlein No, that question is a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @AkibAzmain You’ve pulled me back into history! Wow what an old question. It was already 5 years old when I first commented 7 years ago! Interestingly, comparative age isn’t definitive criteria for selecting which is the duplicate, but in this case it looks like the other was marked as the duplicate ages ago so it’s a moot question. Have a good day!

Comment: see also [OS specific instructions in CMAKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160335/os-specific-instructions-in-cmake-how-to) (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME)

Comment: Are you sure you want to detect the OS the compiler is running **on**, or do you rather want to figure out what OS the compiler is compiling **for**?

Answer (score 457, accepted):

The **[Predefined Macros for OS](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/)** site has a very complete list of checks. Here are a few of them, with links to where they're found:

### [Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx)

`_WIN32`   Both 32 bit and 64 bit
`_WIN64`   64 bit only
`__CYGWIN__`

### Unix (Linux, *BSD, but not Mac OS X)

See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063303/) on some of the pitfalls of using this check.

`unix`
`__unix`
`__unix__`

### Mac OS X

`__APPLE__` Also used for classic
`__MACH__`

Both are defined; checking for either should work.

### [Linux](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/GCC-HOWTO.html)

`__linux__`
`linux`  Obsolete (not POSIX compliant)
`__linux` Obsolete (not POSIX compliant)

### [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/porting-versions.html)

`__FreeBSD__`

### Android

`__ANDROID__`

Comment: This site given does not include iOS, so it fails to be able to distinguish between iOS and OS X.

Comment: Mac OS does not define `__unix__`. Why would you include it in the list?

Comment: cpp -dM /dev/null   will give you a list of all the gcc predefined macro on your version of installed gcc

Comment: Cygwin defines the `unix` symbols and doesn't define the `win32` ones, so be careful. OTOH it does define `__CYGWIN__`.

Comment: is ```__linux__``` same as ```__ANDROID__``` ??

Comment: Why is `__linux ` not POSIX compliant?

Comment: The Windows link is broken

Comment: `_AIX` for IBM AIX respectively.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili not enough underscores

Answer (score 85):

show GCC defines on Windows:

```
gcc -dM -E - <NUL:
```

on Linux:

```
gcc -dM -E - </dev/null
```

Predefined macros in MinGW:

```
WIN32 _WIN32 __WIN32 __WIN32__ __MINGW32__ WINNT __WINNT __WINNT__ _X86_ i386 __i386
```

on UNIXes:

```
unix __unix__ __unix
```

Comment: Windows and Unices are not the only OSes

Comment: That's handy, but note that  `unix`, `__unix__`, `__unix` don't work on macOS, where only `__APPLE__` and `__MACH__` are defined.

Comment: `gcc` on Linux shows `error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-q’` with `gcc -dM -E - </dev/null`

Answer (score 65):

Based on [nadeausoftware](https://web.archive.org/web/20191012035921/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system) and [Lambda Fairy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249232/6003870).

```
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * Determination a platform of an operation system
 * Fully supported supported only GNU GCC/G++, partially on Clang/LLVM
 */

#if defined(_WIN32)
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "windows" // Windows
#elif defined(_WIN64)
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "windows" // Windows
#elif defined(__CYGWIN__) && !defined(_WIN32)
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "windows" // Windows (Cygwin POSIX under Microsoft Window)
#elif defined(__ANDROID__)
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "android" // Android (implies Linux, so it must come first)
#elif defined(__linux__)
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "linux" // Debian, Ubuntu, Gentoo, Fedora, openSUSE, RedHat, Centos and other
#elif defined(__unix__) || !defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    #include <sys/param.h>
    #if defined(BSD)
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "bsd" // FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, DragonFly BSD
    #endif
#elif defined(__hpux)
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "hp-ux" // HP-UX
#elif defined(_AIX)
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "aix" // IBM AIX
#elif defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__) // Apple OSX and iOS (Darwin)
    #include <TargetConditionals.h>
    #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR == 1
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "ios" // Apple iOS
    #elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE == 1
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "ios" // Apple iOS
    #elif TARGET_OS_MAC == 1
        #define PLATFORM_NAME "osx" // Apple OSX
    #endif
#elif defined(__sun) && defined(__SVR4)
    #define PLATFORM_NAME "solaris" // Oracle Solaris, Open Indiana
#else
    #define PLATFORM_NAME NULL
#endif

// Return a name of platform, if determined, otherwise - an empty string
const char *get_platform_name() {
    return (PLATFORM_NAME == NULL) ? "" : PLATFORM_NAME;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts(get_platform_name());
    return 0;
}
```

Tested with GCC and clang on:

- Debian 8
- Windows (MinGW)
- Windows (Cygwin)

Comment: the dear @MD XF,  please indicate versions of your Windows, MinGW and Cygwin

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise 6.1.7601. Cygwin 2.7.0-1. I can't find the MinGW version but I downloaded it yesterday.

Comment: You should probably be made aware though - this program is standard C, so it should work on all compliant systems.

Comment: dear @MD XF, thank you for this information. I added you as contributor on top this answer.

Comment: This way `_WIN64`, can never be defined because `_WIN32` is defined for both.

Answer (score 10):

## Microsoft C/C++ compiler (MSVC) Predefined Macros can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019)

I think you are looking for:

> - `_WIN32` - Defined as 1 when the compilation target is 32-bit ARM, 64-bit ARM, x86, or x64. Otherwise, undefined
> - `_WIN64` - Defined as 1 when the compilation target is 64-bit ARM or x64. Otherwise, undefined.

## gcc compiler PreDefined MAcros can be found [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html)

I think you are looking for:

> - `__GNUC__`
> - `__GNUC_MINOR__`
> - `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__`

Do a google for your appropriate compilers pre-defined.

Answer (score 9):

On MinGW, the `_WIN32` define check isn't working. Here's a solution:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__CYGWIN__)
    // Windows (x86 or x64)
    // ...
#elif defined(__linux__)
    // Linux
    // ...
#elif defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    // Mac OS
    // ...
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
    // Unix like OS
    // ...
#else
    #error Unknown environment!
#endif
```

For more information please look: https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

Comment: best answer as it covers cygwin.

Answer (score 8):

In most cases it is better to check whether a given functionality is present or not. For example: if the function `pipe()` exists or not.

Comment: is there an easy way to check out if a function is defined ?

Comment: If you are using autoconfig you can check for functions with AC_CHECK_FUNCS(). AC_CHECK_FUNCS(pipe sqrt) will define HAVE_PIPE and HAVE_SQRT if the functions are available. I don't know how it is with other building tools, but I guess they also support this in a way.

Comment: @MDXF As of C++17, there is __has_include. I don't think it's standardized in C yet, but all major compilers (GCC, Clang, ICC, MSVC) implement it as a vendor-specific extension, even in C mode.

Answer (score 8):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
// do something for windows like include <windows.h>
#elif defined __unix__
// do something for unix like include <unistd.h>
#elif defined __APPLE__
// do something for mac
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard macro that is set according to C standard. Some C compilers will set one on some platforms (e.g. Apple's patched GCC sets a macro to indicate that it is compiling on an Apple system and for the Darwin platform). Your platform and/or your C compiler might set something as well, but there is no general way.

Like hayalci said, it's best to have these macros set in your build process somehow. It is easy to define a macro with most compilers without modifying the code. You can simply pass `-D MACRO` to GCC, i.e.

```
gcc -D Windows
gcc -D UNIX
```

And in your code:

```
#if defined(Windows)
// do some cool Windows stuff
#elif defined(UNIX)
// do some cool Unix stuff
#else
#    error Unsupported operating system
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the external reference, but I think it is suited to your question:

[C/C++ tip: How to detect the operating system type using compiler predefined macros](https://web.archive.org/web/20191012035921/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system)

Comment: That meta post was removed. Funny that a meta post asking about posts removed for reasons of moderation was removed for reasons of moderation.

Comment: :) Yeah. Absolutely crazy

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Boost.Predef`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/predef/doc/index.html) which contains various predefined macros for the target platform including the OS (`BOOST_OS_*`). Yes boost is often thought as a C++ library, but this one is a preprocessor header that **works with C as well!**

> This library defines a set of compiler, architecture, operating system, library, and other version numbers from the information it can gather of C, C++, Objective C, and Objective C++ predefined macros or those defined in generally available headers. The idea for this library grew out of a proposal to extend the Boost Config library to provide more, and consistent, information than the feature definitions it supports. What follows is an edited version of that brief proposal.

For example

```
#include <boost/predef.h>
// or just include the necessary header
// #include <boost/predef/os.h>

#if   BOOST_OS_WINDOWS
#elif BOOST_OS_ANDROID
#elif BOOST_OS_LINUX
#elif BOOST_OS_BSD
#elif BOOST_OS_AIX
#elif BOOST_OS_HAIKU
...
#endif
```

The full list can be found in [`BOOST_OS` operating system macros](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/predef/doc/index.html#_boost_os_operating_system_macros)

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMxqkrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAzKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/oGp6Y4CoeFRLLHxXEl2mA6ZQgRMxATZPn4Btpj2RQwNTQQlkTFxibaNza25HQrjA2FD5SNVAJS2qF7EyOwc5glhyN5YANQmCW7RqGkEAPTJxJhYVAB0CKfYJhoAgtfXRyRH2i8MyO%2B0OmCOBAQ4PCWwUCiaAE8jlCmFhiB9vr9dqCvMdTudLjNbvdHtc0i83hiMWECEdgJgCAB5IQQZZUgDsVi%2B2KoRwsjOZABUAPrM4UAdQAkhEACKM8VCDFHZUq5X3AgbBhHLhmU5cz67Lp4Xn8oWioTC4LSuQADSVqpV6s1RzMCT1VNdRpNAqEIrFFiEMvtDqOTuIWoSknd3M9tGNfJ9fotAFlPm5mcGHWGtZIAKzRg2xpSZ1XZo65gBsBcNDHwVA5Qa%2BHFWtE4ud4fg4WlIqE4bms1iOCnWm3Bux4pAImmbqwA1iBI09JGYuABOSQVySSDSu3NSfScSQd6c9zi8BQgQJTrvN0hwWAwRAoVAsZJ0OLkShoV/v%2BIAN2QZJkmFP812FBIzGFVRNz4OgCDiC8IGiE9ojCRFOAnb82EERkGFoBETywFhDGAcQb1IfB7jqP9MAvcjMFUWovHgjDeBpLoTzjaJiERDwsBPAhiDwFhWNWKgDGABQADU8EwAB3RlkkYViZEEEQxHYfd%2BEERQVHUcjdC4fQSJQAdLH0PBogvWBmDYEALiuUgaP/QDZ2AZZVlQZIejo65GS4I5rnFI8UkMSJWHYcUwnQVA5IUTpukyFxa0mPwKzMIJa0GMoKhAaQCgyARUpAdKUjSQqGGy4Z4mkGo6gEPoJk8NoSoyuqekauZSmqvKxn6YrSpmfoqsWGrVmHDYtj0QTMG2HgWzbY9yN7KLa1i%2BLry0VYICQb833oMgKAgPbfxAFg8GSBRK0kLpYNoeDiEQ5DyNQ5hiAI7heCwxgmTwj7uyIkiyIBvAqMcGi6O7BimJY8j2NbciuJ496%2BO2btBOE0S%2BAk6TZIUpTOwnbThFEcQtNkXS1BPXQK2MoxTMsawLKs%2BAIFs9gHJmJyRm4dlVxnHtvMyOiAFp/KOEXxTEWgJfFBjBKYXhkjCiIIpAEovFUBLah6ZL3Ga3I80y9ARtypICp6YqjYtzJTZGaouh1%2BpZit3Ntfq3pZjt%2BJqhdg2/CNobmm9hdxpHKajJmubbwR9tSE7btew1rXNoFlE0UoOc8q4JcuHSgAOStcwCPmzDdhGQpE3NAgT3hew4c9punbbHx258fwOz9jpffaRiaFg/3zkWDhIrguA0IyaHuhDKGe7tXvQz7SG%2BnC/sIzBiKMYHeEop2IZPaHkGY6PyEEDjEcs5GEVRgShJEz6xJxmT5MU5Sl%2BJ9SyekYnKf07tdGkAYemphGbmS4tZKA7N7KEgINzeIvN%2BYeUFj5TgYszCy2lrLeWPEJbjHpLSVQ%2BcKzCk3CLJgQF6Ai3QE0OSYQpDDyAcAJWKs1bEWQMyd2usICuGKkZEI8wcpLDKoUTIvDhEVRDkZdqzt%2Br%2Bz0NIhqXsBE9SkX7HIfhVHDWUaNCQYdJqaUnPcaOC0OBx1rqeNhHDU7bV2j3X8XcToHRAOgbQwBgDJHZB0KeD0nooTQu9FSK9fr4XXpvUiaMd6gz3rRA%2BjEj6wwnPDTil9eIYAiYYzGD9sZMEks/fGb8iayE/ppb%2BFMlBUwMiAVcdNjBmRsOA1mUDOawOchhPmAsvIoI4GgjBtAZaS2wYrUKpQ1ZyiEJwpK3CUpyL4VlbRuUjI2yKjM8RPRJETMUbI9R8jHYe06usoOLQVmHMkXo0c00jFY1jktROIAxmTmbqsdOIxWQHg4JXEA1d44nnro3K8jzSDzgrLmJ4uZ2T5w0LmBIuZcyrnZJuQubyEg3LrmeB5N4kEIzMCi08Dd0VbVWM5dIzhJBAA)

See also [How to get platform IDs from boost?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46090534/995714)

Answer (score 2):

Use `#define OSsymbol` and `#ifdef OSsymbol`
where OSsymbol is a `#define`'able symbol identifying your target OS.

Typically you would include a central header file defining the selected OS symbol and use OS-specific include and library directories to compile and build.

You did not specify your development environment, but I'm pretty sure your compiler provides global defines for common platforms and OSes.

See also http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor

Answer (score 2):

Just to sum it all up, here are a bunch of helpful links.

- [GCC Common Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros)
- [SourceForge predefined Operating Systems](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/)
- [MSDN Predefined Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros)
- [The Much-Linked NaudeaSoftware Page](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system)
- [Wikipedia!!!](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor)
- [SourceForge's "Overview of pre-defined compiler macros for standards, compilers, operating systems, and hardware architectures."](http://predef.sourceforge.net/prestd.html)
- [FreeBSD's "Differentiating Operating Systems"](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/porting-versions.html)
- [All kinds of predefined macros](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/)
- [`libportable`](https://github.com/aaronryank/libportable)

Answer (score 1):

I did not find [Haiku](https://www.haiku-os.org) definition here. To be complete, Haiku-os definition is simple `__HAIKU__`

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    std::cout << "Running on Windows" << std::endl;
#elif __linux__
    std::cout << "Running on Linux" << std::endl;
#elif __APPLE__
    std::cout << "Running on macOS" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "Unknown operating system" << std::endl;
#endif
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers will generate #defines that can help you with this. Read the compiler documentation to determine what they are. [MSVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) defines one that's `__WIN32__`, [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) has some you can see with `touch foo.h; gcc -dM foo.h`

Comment: gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--show-defines'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: The MSVC link above currently redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170 - and that lists a `_WIN32` macro but not `__WIN32__`. I've also looked at an archived version - https://web.archive.org/web/20100422132954/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.80).aspx - and that also lists `_WIN32` but not `__WIN32__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pre-processor directives** as ***warning or error*** to check at compile time you don't need to **run** this program at all just simply **compile** it .

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
    #error Windows_OS
#elif defined(__linux__)
    #error Linux_OS
#elif defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    #error Mach_OS
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
    #error Unix_OS
#else
    #error Unknown_OS
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this was down-voted. Great idea here, not needing to run it just for checking prep's. I suppose you need to enable all warnings in the compiler. For gcc, use `-Wall`. `#warning` may be even better, to avoid stopping the compile, but only seem to work in GCC and not MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but wanted to share my personal usage:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__)
#   define TL_PLATFORM_WINDOWS 1
#   ifndef _WIN64
#       error "64-bit is required on Windows!"
#   endif
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__gnu_linux__)
#   define TL_PLATFORM_LINUX 1
#   if defined(__ANDROID__)
#       define TL_PLATFORM_ANDROID 1
#   endif
#elif defined(__unix__)
#   define TL_PLATFORM_UNIX 1
#elif defined(_POSIX_VERSION)
#   define TL_PLATFORM_POSIX 1
#elif __APPLE__
#   define TL_PLATFORM_APPLE 1
#   include <TargetConditionals.h>
#   if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#       define TL_PLATFORM_IOS 1
#       define TL_PLATFORM_IOS_SIMULATOR 1
#   elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#       define TL_PLATFORM_IOS 1
#   elif TARGET_OS_MAC
#   else
#       error "Unknown Apple platform"
#   endif
#else
#   error "Unknown platform!"
#endif
```

On my C projects thats my standard platform detection macro.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote an [small library](https://github.com/abranhe/os.c) to get the operating system you are on, it can be installed using [clib](https://clibs.org) (The C package manager), so it is really simple to use it as a dependency for your projects.

#### Install

```
$ clib install abranhe/os.c
```

#### Usage

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "os.h"

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", operating_system());
    // macOS
    return 0;
}
```

It returns a string (`char*`) with the name of the operating system you are using, for further information about this project check it out [the documentation on Github](https://github.com/abranhe/os.c/blob/master/readme.md#api).