# _AMD64_ not defined in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

I created a new c++ project in VS2010. I added x64 as a new solution platform. I tried setting "copy settings from" to both "Win32" and "empty", but neither worked. `_AMD64_` is not defined when I select x64 as the platform. Shouldn't it be? Is there another step I am unaware of for compiling for 64 bit?

In anticipation to questions: I am using VS2010 Ultimate, Windows 7 64bit, x64 compilers were selected during VS installation.

Comment: Using _WIN64/WIN64 macros - http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0040/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got all the steps right. An `_AMD64_` symbol is *not* predefined by default by Visual Studio. You'll need to define it yourself if you want to use it:

```
#if defined _M_X64 || defined _M_AMD64
    #define _AMD64_
#endif
```

But you're not making up the memory of its existence. The Windows DDK comes with makefiles that define this symbol, in addition to some others. Check in `makefile.def`. The possibilities are:

- `_X86_`
  Variously known as x86, i386, and IA-32
  (this is the same as VS's predefined `_M_IX86`)
- `_AMD64_`
  Variously known as AMD64, x64, x86-64, IA-32e, and Intel 64
  (this is the same as VS's predefined `_M_X64` and `_M_AMD64`)
- `_IA64_`
  Intel Itanium (IA-64)
  (this is the same as VS's predefined `_M_IA64`)
- …and some others for architectures nobody targets anymore

Ideally, you would configure your build system to predefine a set of known macros that you will then use in your own code. If you don't have a build system, at least set something up in a precompiled header file. That way, you're not relying on implementation-dependent symbols *everywhere*, and switching compilers is not a colossal chore—the target architecture symbols predefined by GCC are very different from MSVC, for example.