# C1189 "No target architecture" when building a driver

Tags: c++, windows, driver, minifilter

I am trying to run a simple driver for windows, but am getting the following error:
`C1189 #error: "No Target Architecture" C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\shared\ntdef.h`
My code:

```
#include <sdkddkver.h>

#include <ntddk.h>
#include <wdf.h>
DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;
EVT_WDF_DRIVER_DEVICE_ADD KmdfHelloWorldEvtDeviceAdd;

_Use_decl_annotations_
VOID
DriverUnload(
)
{
    KdPrint(("This is driver Exit \r\n"));
}

NTSTATUS
DriverEntry(
    _In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT     DriverObject,
    _In_ PUNICODE_STRING    RegistryPath
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);
    // NTSTATUS variable to record success or failure
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
    KdPrint(("This is driver entry \r\n"));

    return status;
}
```

`ntddk.h` includes `ntdef.h` which is where the error happens:

```
#if defined(_AMD64_) || defined(_X86_)
#define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) TYPE_ALIGNMENT( ULONG )
#elif defined(_IA64_) || defined(_ARM_) || defined(_ARM64_)

#define PROBE_ALIGNMENT( _s ) TYPE_ALIGNMENT( ULONG )
#elif !defined(RC_INVOKED)
#error "No Target Architecture" // error
#endif
```

I have tried multiple other sample programs and always end up getting this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545010/amd64-not-defined-in-vs2010

Comment: Adding those macros doesn't make a difference, it still gives the same errors.

Comment: because you need define it. if we include *windows.h* here exist code which define this. you can copy-paste this code