# Detecting CPU architecture (32bit / 64bit ) in scons?

Tags: build-process, scons, cpu-architecture

Are there any 'standard' plugins for detecting the CPU architecture in **scons**?

BTW, this question was asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152016/detecting-cpu-architecture-compile-time) in a more general form... just wondering if anyone has already taken the time to incorporate this information into scons.

Answer (score 6):

Using **i386** is rather compiler dependant, and won't detect non x86 32 bits archs. Assuming the python interpreter used by scons runs on the CPU you are interested in (not always the case - think cross compilation), you can just use python itself.

```
import platform
print platform.machine()
print platform.architecture()
```

If you need something more sophisticated, then maybe you will have to write your own configure function - but it may be better to deal with it in your code directly.

Comment: Note that this does the wrong thing in a 32bit userspace chroot with a 64bit kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
env = Environment()
conf = Configure(env)
if conf.CheckDeclaration("__i386__"):
    conf.Define("MY_ARCH", "blahblablah")
env = conf.Finish()
```