# Checking the sizeof an integer type in the preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, sizeof

How can I check the size of an `unsigned` in the preprocessor under g++? `sizeof` is out of the question since it is not defined when during preprocessing.

Comment: It is not well answered there.

Comment: @Lucero: That only answers why sizeof is out of the question that myahya is aware of.

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505582/determining-32-vs-64-bit-in-c covers your question?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant method, but one thing that you may be able to leverage is UINT_MAX defined in "limits.h".  That is, ...

if UINT_MAX == 65535, then you would know that sizeof (unsigned) = 2

if UINT_MAX == 4294967295, then you would know that sizeof (unsigned) = 4.

and so on.

As I said, not elegant, but it should provide some level of usability.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a valid answer that is not in the "duplicate" question. So, I've voted to reopen.

Comment: The preprocessor should be able to do some math, something like `#if UINT_MAX >> 8 == 0 // 1 byte` ... `#elif UINT_MAX >> 16 == 0 //two bytes` etc?

Comment: Technically the size of the integer could be bigger than this technique predicts, since `unsigned` is allowed to have padding bits, or smaller since CHAR_BIT need not be 8. So for correctness it might be worth also asserting somewhere (in a test, perhaps), that `sizeof` does give the size expected. In practice you can say with high confidence that it isn't gonna happen.

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer just to get around the need for explicitly plugging in values.

Comment: If `UCHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX` then `sizeof(1U)` _probably_ is one. But it still may be 3.

Comment: You assume `CHAR_BIT==8`, which is not a requirement.

Answer (score 11):

Based on Sparky's answer, here is a way that would look a bit nicer (by eliminating the explicit numbers)

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//Check if size if 4bytes
#if UINT_MAX == UINT32_MAX

....

#endif
```

`<limits.h>` defines `INT_MAX` and `<stdint.h>` defines `UINT32_MAX`. Generally, [`<stdint.h>`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html) gives integer types with specified widths.

Comment: This works under gcc, under g++ it can be problematic. Sparky's solution is more general

Comment: The problem is that what if UINT_MAX doesn't fit into a preprocessor integer? The preprocessor arithmetic in `#if` directives works with a signed type. Modern ISO C defines that as being the type `intmax_t`: the widest signed type available in the implementation. What if `unsigned int` has the same width? Then `UINT_MAX` is out of range.  Can we trust that there will be an implementation-defined conversion in the `#if` directive, like in an ordinary C expression?