# Initializing a const array with size sizeof(int)

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, sizeof

If I wanted to initialize an array of constant integers in c++ that has size sizeof(int), how would I go about doing that? For example, I might want an array such that it has sizeof(int)*8 ints with the nth bit on (array[n]=1 << n).

Comment: Look at this SO entry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050559/how-to-initialize-a-const-char-array-data-member-with-c

Comment: If you are playing with bits, use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset), it makes your life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can initialize a statically sized array of `const` objects without specifying each element, at least, not when it isn't a member of class. You can, however, initialize a reference to a statically sized array of `const` objects:

```
template <int N>
struct foo
{
    static bool init(int* array) {
        unsigned int bit(1);
        for (int i(0); i != N; ++i) {
            array[i] = bit << i;
        }
        return true;
    }
    static void use(bool) {}
    static int const (&array())[N] {
        static int rc[N];
        static bool dummy(init(rc));
        use(dummy);
        return rc;
    }
};

int const (&array)[sizeof(int) * 8] = foo<sizeof(int) * 8>::array();
```

If you really want to initialize a statically sized array, you *can* do it using variadic templates but the array would need to be a static member of a class type. Since the code isn't quite as obvious, here it is:

```
template <int...> struct indices {};
template <int N, typename> struct make_list;
template <int... Indices>
struct make_list<0, indices<Indices...>> {
    typedef indices<0, Indices...> type;
};
template <int N, int... Indices>
struct make_list<N, indices<Indices...>> {
    typedef typename make_list<N-1, indices<N, Indices...>>::type type;
};

template <int N, typename> struct array_aux;
template <int N, int... Indices>
struct array_aux<N, indices<Indices...>>
{
    static int const values[N];
};

template <int N, int... Indices>
int const array_aux<N, indices<Indices...>>::values[N] = { 1u << Indices... };

template <int N = sizeof(int) * 8>
struct array
    : array_aux<N, typename make_list<N-1, indices<>>::type>
{
};
```

With that you could then access the array using something like this:

```
array<>::values[i]
```

Comment: I think these are the closest solutions to what I want. I was hoping there was some sort of way to invoke macro recursion but was saddened to learned that that would be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to initialize a constant array of 4 integers where sizeof(int) == 4:

```
#define SHIFT(__n) (1 << __n++)

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    const int ir4[sizeof(int)] = {SHIFT(n), SHIFT(n), SHIFT(n), SHIFT(n)};

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though I would like to be able to initialize it without knowing the value of sizeof(int) in advance.

Comment: If the requirement is strictly based on sizeof(int), there are some clever ways to determine the sizeof(int) on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584937/checking-the-sizeof-an-integer-type-in-the-preprocessor. With this, the preprocessor could be used to determine the correct initializer. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::array and a template

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
std::array<T, sizeof(T)*N> array_init() {
    std::array<T, sizeof(T)*N> ints;
    for (T n = 0; n < sizeof(T)*N; ++n) {
    ints[n] = 1 << n;
    }
    return ints;
}
```

Then you call it like

```
auto ints = array_init<int, 8>();
```