# how to tell if 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit, bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determining 32 vs 64 bit in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505582/determining-32-vs-64-bit-in-c)

Is there any way, independent of the platform, to get the platform bit size easily using c++? Im trying to use ttmath, and one of the requirements of its syntax is the number of words per integer. To avoid wasting space, I need to know how many words are needed for each integer