# Determining mxClassID of mwSize at mex file

Tags: matlab, 32bit-64bit, mex

I'm using the mxCreateNumericMatrix function at my mex file:

```
mxArray *mxCreateNumericMatrix(mwSize m, mwSize n, mxClassID classid, mxComplexity ComplexFlag);
```

I want to get array of type **mwSize**.
For that I need to determine if using **mxUINT32_CLASS** or **mxUINT64_CLASS** as **classid**.

I can determine it in runtime with if statement on **sizeof(mwSize)**, but is there a more elegant way to determine the class ID of mwSize? Maybe some define that depends on the system which has one value or the other?

Just a matter of aesthetics.

BTW, at Fortran there is a function mxClassIDFromClassName:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxclassidfromclassname.html

mwSize is used for among the other reasons, so that the mxCreateDoubleMatrix function will be portable. It is strange if no elegant solution exists for mxCreateNumericMatrix.

Edit:

As @Praetorian explained, in my case I have no reason to use the type that fits the system (32 or 64 bits), as I specifically prefer it to be 64-bit integer array, and I can define this size also in 32-bit system.

But on the other hand, I also want to return two indices to the array that I return. In my case, I know that the array itself is short, and I use `uint16_T` anyway, but if I wanted it to fit the `mwIndex`, I would have to use some macro (@Amro suggested some good options), because apparently, there is no function as `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` for integers (that fits the system).

To sum it up, @Praetorian helped me with my case in the comments below and @Amro gave probably the best options available for the general case.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: @Praetorian I'm using **C**

Comment: In that case your best option for determining 32/64 bit at compile time is to use macros. Perhaps `#if SIZE_MAX == UINT64_MAX` will work

Comment: I hadn't actually read your question completely earlier. I don't understand why you want to create a matrix containing `mwSize` elements; typically one creates matrices containing one of the [mxClassID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxclassid.html) types, at least if you want to be able to operate on that matrix from the MATLAB side. Maybe if you could explain your use case a bit more, an alternative solution can be found.

Comment: @Praetorian
I create the matrix (actually an array) in order to return it as an **output parameter of the mex function**.
 I used the `mwSize` because it was explained at the documentation about mex file that it's the way to do it if you want your code to be portable (they also mentioned `mwIndex`). In the example I saw, they used `mxCreateDoubleMatrix` function, and I searched for alternative function, for returning integer type.

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the documentation. To create a matrix (or vector) use `mxCreateNumericMatrix` with the appropriate `mxClassID` depending on the data type of elements you want. When you have a variable in your code referring to the *size* of a matrix, make sure the type of that variable is `mwSize`. This ensures that when you recompile the mex source when switching platforms, everything will compile and function correctly. That's the portability they're talking about, not binary portability as you seem to have interpreted that as.

Comment: @Praetorian If I use mxUINT64_CLASS and I'm at 32-bit system, I guess it will give me an error rather than interpret it as mxUINT32_CLASS (which maybe would be reasonable in this case). Right?

Comment: It'll do neither. You can create a matrix containing 64-bit integers even if you're on a 32-bit system.

Comment: @Praetorian 
You are right. Anyway I've already replaced all the definitions of integers to uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t etc, as was suggested.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The goal of `mxCreateNumericMatrix` and other `mxCreate*` functions is to create an `mxArray` (MATLAB fundamental type). Such arrays can be returned to MATLAB from the MEX-function.

[`mwSize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mwsize.html) is just a `typedef` to a `size_t` type (might be different for 32-bit vs. 64-bit), which is not a valid MATLAB datatype (not part of [`mxClassID`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxclassid.html)). If actually you want to create an array of `mwSize`, allocate memory in C the usual way `mxMalloc` (but I doubt this is what you want in this case).

---

As Praetorian notes, the actual C type to which `mwSize` and `mwIndex` are typedef'ed is determined by the flags you pass to the `mex` command (or the default value if you didnt explicitly specify one):

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims file.c
>> mex -compatibleArrayDims file.c
```

If we inspect the `tmwtypes.h` header file which gets included, here is the relevant block of code:

```
#ifdef MX_COMPAT_32
typedef int mwSize;
typedef int mwIndex;
typedef int mwSignedIndex;
#else
typedef size_t    mwSize;         /* unsigned pointer-width integer */
typedef size_t    mwIndex;        /* unsigned pointer-width integer */
typedef ptrdiff_t mwSignedIndex;  /* a signed pointer-width integer */
#endif
```

(Recall that `size_t` is itself platform-dependent).

---

As mentioned in the comments above, I think you are misinterpreting the documentation. `mwIndex` and `mwSize` are meant to be used when indexing into a matrix and when dealing with matrix sizes respectively when writing MEX-function (instead of using non-portable plain `int`). They do not have corresponding `mxClassID` (so you cannot create `mxArray`'s of those types and pass them back to MATLAB).

Now if you want to create an array of indices and return it to MATLAB to be used as a regular variable, you could create an `mxArray` of the equivalent type to unsigned integers (matching the bit-ness of your architecture: 32-bit vs 64-bit). Use [macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505582/determining-32-vs-64-bit-in-c) to determine which one you are compiling for, and use `mxUINT32_CLASS` or `mxUINT64_CLASS` accordingly.

For example, we could use the same macro MATLAB is using:

```
#ifdef MX_COMPAT_32
typedef mxUINT32_CLASS INDICES_CLASS;
#else
typedef mxUINT64_CLASS INDICES_CLASS;
#endif

mxArray *arr = mxCreateNumericMatrix(10, 1, INDICES_CLASS, mxReal);
// ... fill arr with indices
```

Comment: `mwSize` can also be `int` if the `-largeArrayDims` switch is not passed to the mex function (I believe this switch is set by default)

Comment: I create the matrix in order to return it as an output parameter of the mex function. I used the mwSize because it was explained at the documentation about mex file that it's the way to do it if you want your code to be portable (they also mentioned mwIndex). 
This is my first time using mex file, and I'm pretty new with Matlab, so I followed the recommendations.
I don't know if I can return the matrix using mxMalloc, but I see that I still would have to determine if it's 32-bit or 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mxClassIDFromClassName` in C? According to [this list](http://www.advanpix.com/downloads/libmx_api.txt) of undocumented libmx functions [discussed here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-matlab-mex-api/), it seems to exist. But yes, if you want to stick to what is listed in the online documentation, I don't know of a way other than using an `if` statement. Creating things other than double matrices in mex is always messier.