# Loading executable or executing a library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, executable, glibc, dlopen

There is a [large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449987/building-a-so-that-is-also-an-executable) [number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937745/how-to-compile-elf-binary-so-that-it-can-be-loaded-as-dynamic-library?noredirect=1&lq=1) of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617679/using-dlopen-on-an-executable) on SO about how to execute a library or dynamically load an executable. As far as I can tell, all the answers come down to: compile your executable as position-independent code and load it with `dlopen`. This worked great --- and still works great on macOS --- until a [recent change in glibc](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/1055380/), which explicitly disabled `dlopen`ing PIEs. This change is now in the current version of glibc (2.30) on ArchLinux, for example, and trying to `dlopen` a position-independent executable gives an error: "cannot dynamically load position-independent executable".

It's difficult to guess what prompted such a radical change that breaks so much code and useful use cases. (The explanations on Patchwork and Bugzilla don't make much sense to me.) But there is now a question: what to do if you want to create an executable that's also a dynamic library, or vice versa?

[A solution](http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/executable_lib.html) was linked from one of the comments. Reproducing it here for posterity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char service_interp[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";

extern "C" {

void lib_entry(void)
{
  printf("Entry point of the service library\n");    
  _exit(0);
}

}
```

Compiling with `g++ -shared test-no-pie.cpp -o test-no-pie -Wl,-e,lib_entry` produces a shared object (dynamic library) that can also be executed on Linux.

I have two questions:

1. What if I want to pass command-line arguments? How to modify this solution so it accepts `arc,argv`?
2. Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change interpreter path and pass command line arguments to an "executable" shared library on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652446/how-to-change-interpreter-path-and-pass-command-line-arguments-to-an-executable)

Answer (score 6):

> It's difficult to guess what prompted such a radical change

Not really: it never worked correctly.

> that breaks so much code

That code was broken already in subtle ways. Now you get a clear indication that it will not work.

> Are there other alternatives?

Don't do that?

What problem does `dlopen`ing an executable solve?

If it's a real problem, open a GLIBC bugzilla feature request, explaining that problem and requesting a supported mechanism to achieve desired result.

**Update:**

> at least say why "it never worked correctly". Is it some triviality like potentially clashing globals between the executables, or something real?

Thread-local variables is an example that doesn't work correctly. Whether you think they are "real" or not I have no idea.

Here is the code:

```
// foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

__thread int var;

__attribute__((constructor))
static void init()
{
  var = 42;
  printf("foo.c init: %d %p\n", var, &var);
}

int bar() {
  printf("foo.c bar:  %d %p\n", var, &var);
  return var;
}

int main()
{
  printf("foo.c main: %d %p bar()=%d\n", var, &var, bar());
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -g foo.c -o foo -Wl,-E -fpie -pie && ./foo
foo.c init: 42 0x7fb5dfd7d4fc
foo.c bar:  42 0x7fb5dfd7d4fc
foo.c main: 42 0x7fb5dfd7d4fc bar()=42
```

```
// main.c
// Error checking omitted for brevity
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  void *h1 = dlopen("./foo", RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_LAZY);
  int (*bar)(void) = dlsym(h1, "bar");

  printf("main.c: %d\n", bar());
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -g main.c -ldl && ./a.out
foo.c init: 42 0x7fb7305da73c
foo.c bar:  0 0x7fb7305da73c    <<< what?
main.c: 0                       <<< what?
```

This is using `GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10) stable release version 2.28.`

Bottom line: this was never designed to work, and you just happened to not step on many of the land-mines, so you thought it is working, when in fact you were exercising undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the example. So globals are the problem. Still seems like throwing the baby out with the bathwater. Also, what's the reason this works if I compile `foo.c` as a shared library? I.e., how are the two situations different?

Comment: I agree...we've used executable shared libraries for the convenience in having a shared library that is debugable by running it as standlone with GDB.
(instead of compiling another executable that `dlopen` and run main)
However, we saw many subtle problems including global variables...

Comment: The example code would work correctly provided that it's compiled with `-fPIC`( as already demonstrated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659713/why-does-dynamically-loading-of-pies-no-longer-work-in-glibc?noredirect=1&lq=1)). As such, it doesn't prove anything, and until more evidence is brought out, everything in this answer should be considered only opinion and baseless claims.

Comment: @foxcub globals are not the problem.

Comment: "What problem does dlopening an executable solve?" Usually the question is not about dlopening an executable, but about executing a shared library.

Answer (score 3):

Please see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339111/14760867

The `argc`, `argv` question is not answered there, but when I found I needed one, I hacked something together to parse `/proc/self/cmdline` at runtime for [`pam_cap.so`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/libcap/execable.h) use.