# Why does dynamically loading of PIEs no longer work in glibc?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, glibc, dlopen, position-independent-code

**Note:** The purported [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59079758/10760539) does NOT answer this question in any way; in particular, the thread-local example can be easily fixed by compiling with `-fPIC`, just like the bugzilla example already mentioned below. And the rest is just unasked-for opinions and baseless claims.

---

In recent Linux systems like Debian 10, RHEL 8, etc you can create an ELF file which is both a position independent executable (PIE) and a dynamically loaded library / shared object at the same time.

This is very useful, and has a lot of applications, like e.g. creating wrapper programs which *preload themselves* and then execute another program (see **Exhibit 2** below), or having a virtual machine / language environment as a single object which could be either embedded or run as a standalone interpreter. All without having to deal with hardwired installation directories, symlink exploits, `$ORIGIN`s or other such security and filesystem policy nightmares.

However, change [2c75b54](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=2c75b545de6fe3c44138799c68217a94bc669a88) in glibc broke it:

> elf: Refuse to dlopen PIE objects [BZ #24323]
>
> Another executable has already been mapped, so the dynamic linker
> cannot perform relocations correctly for the second executable

also claiming in the [discussion](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11754#c13) which led to it that:

> There is also no way to correctly execute the ELF constructors of the second executable

But that seems bogus. As shown by **Exhibit 1** below, constructors, relocations and thread-local variables seem to work fine.

*Copy relocations* do not work, but is there any reason to also break programs which do *not* use *copy relocations*, as those compiled with `-fPIC`? (In particular, the [testcase](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11754#c15) from that [discussion](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11754) could be easily fixed by just compiling it with `-fPIC`).

This change was also [picked](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/commit/69c1ac3538df) in FreeBSD 12.2, the main reason given being that "glibc does it too". It still works in NetBSD 9.1 and OpenBSD 6.8 (though constructors do not work in OpenBSD).

So, what are the technical reasons why using PIEs in this manner should not work? Clear scenarios where this would break (see the challenges from Exhibit 1 and 2) would be great.

#### Exhibit 1

The `libexe` program should work the same when **a)** executed directly or **b)** dl-loaded as a shared library and called via its `main` function by `loader`.

The challenge is to demonstrate features that `libexe` could use that would preclude either **a)** or **b)** or cause it to work differently, in ways that cannot be easily fixed.

```
cat <<'EOT' > libexe.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <err.h>

__thread int var;
void set_errno(int e){ errno = e; }

__attribute__((weak))
int main(void){
        set_errno(EPIPE); warn("%s var=%d", __FILE__, var);
}
__attribute__((constructor))
static void init(void){
        var = 33;
        fprintf(stderr, "%s's constructor\n", __FILE__);
}
EOT

cat <<'EOT' > loader.c
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void){
        void *dl; char *lib = "./libexe";

        if(!(dl = dlopen(lib, RTLD_LAZY)))
                errx(1, "dlopen: %s", dlerror());
        printf("var=%d in %s\n", *(int*)dlsym(dl, "var"), __FILE__);
        ((void(*)(int))dlsym(dl, "set_errno"))(EBADF); warn("%s", __FILE__);
        return ((int(*)(void))dlsym(dl, "main"))();
}
__attribute__((constructor))
static void init(void){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s's constructor\n", __FILE__);
}
EOT

cc -pie -fPIC -Wl,-E libexe.c -o libexe
cc loader.c -o loader -ldl

############
$ ./loader
loader.c's constructor
libexe.c's constructor
var=33 in loader.c
loader: loader.c: Bad file descriptor
loader: libexe.c var=33: Broken pipe
```

#### Exhibit 2

This little program *preloads itself* and then runs another executable. Unlike the typical `LD_PRELOAD=/some/path ./cmd`, this would also run fine via [`fexecve`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fexecve.3.html)/[`execveat(AT_EMPTY_PATH)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execveat.2.html) on Linux, as when exec'ing a [`memfd_create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html)d file. It was tested to work on Debian >= 9, Centos/RHEL >= 7, etc.

The challenge is to demonstrate an executable which would fail when chain-exec'ed in this way, but will work fine when the preloaded code is in a separate library, as with [`stdbuf`/`libstdbuf.so`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/stdbuf.c?id=ff80b6b0a0507e24f39cc1aad09d147f5187430b).

```
cat <<'EOT' > read-eio.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int ac, char **av){
        int fd; char buf[32];
        if(ac < 2 || !av[1])
                errx(1, "usage: %s cmd args..", av[0]);
        if((fd = open("/proc/self/exe", O_PATH)) == -1)
                err(1, "open /proc/self/exe");
        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "/dev/fd/%d", fd);
        if(setenv("LD_PRELOAD", buf, 1))
                err(1, "setenv");
        execvp(av[1], av + 1);
        err(1, "execvp %s", av[1]);
}
ssize_t read(int fd, void *b, size_t z){
        errno = EIO; return -1;
}
EOT

cc -fPIC -pie read-eio.c -o read-eio

###########
$ ./read-eio cat
cat: -: Input/output error
```

Comment: If an executable cannot be used as a shared object, maybe you could create a shared object that can be used as an executable.

Comment: @ZsigmondLőrinczy I suppose you mean that there are some linker options / linker scripts which would make a program compiled with `-fPIC -shared` also usable as an executable. What are they?