# Determining when cross compiling for 32 bit from 64-bit in preprocessor?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I used the answer from [Determining 32 vs 64 bit in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505582/determining-32-vs-64-bit-in-c) to make this:

```
#ifndef AVUNA_CFG
#define AVUNA_CFG
#if _WIN32 || _WIN64
#if _WIN64
#define BIT64
#else
#define BIT32
#endif
#endif

// Check GCC
#if __GNUC__
#if __x86_64__ || __ppc64__
#define BIT64
#else
#define BIT32
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

However, this doesn't seem to work when specifying `-m32` to GCC for cross compiling, so it always says `BIT64`. Is there any defines I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Also, for gcc, look at `__LP64__` and `_LP64` for detecting 64bit compiles: "*These macros are defined, with value 1, if (and only if) the compilation is for a target where long int and pointer both use 64-bits and int uses 32-bit*."

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The only time there would be a difference is if someone did `#define _WIN32 0`, and then your suggested code would be worse.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think you can use sizeof in a preprocessor?

Comment: @JavaProphet: You are right.  I forgot about that caveat.

Comment: The recent addition of -mx32 may complicate  full answer to this even further

Comment: If  `__ILP32__` is defined on an otherwise 64 bit system, ARCH=x32... Where the 64 bit system uses  pointers that are 32 bits (and some other minor differences)

Comment: You could setup your Makefile or whatever to also pass a define whenever you pass `-m32`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an Eclipse-define because I have two different run configurations for 32/64-bit cross compile. Works well.