# Gcc extension or macro to check the bits used for some fundamental types at compile time

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

At compile time, with some using `static_assert`s I would like to check the size in bits of some simple type like `unsigned int` or `char`, the important thing that it will be granted to happen at compile time given my usage .

I haven't found anything about this in the `gcc` manual nor I have any knowledge of a similar feature offered by `clang`, anyone knows how to check the number of bits used by a type ?

No sizeof please, my focus is on the **bits** and compile time .

Comment: Why do you think sizeof cannot test at compile time?

Comment: @texasbruce more concerned about the number of bits in the `sizeof` case, I was just making clear the 2 goals that I would like to meet .

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `CHAR_BIT` doesn't suit you? If you want a built-in, Gcc and Clang seem to have `__CHAR_BIT__`...

Comment: @mafso I want to implement that, my problem is to find a viable solution about how to inject the correct value for this kind symbols . `__CHAR_BIT__` really looks like a builtin value, but `__WORDSIZE` is still just a macro . Half of the problem is solved.

Comment: What do you want to implement?

Comment: @mafso I'm not happy with the std, I just need a different implementation and set of features ( like algorithms and containers ), I basically have to implement a small subset of the std and I'm starting from the fundamentals data types . I also need this for X86 and ARM and I'm planning to use `clang` or `gcc` with C++11/14.

Comment: So you want to implement your own standard library? This is built on top of a compiler, which provides `<limits.h>`, as stated in the comments below.

Comment: @mafso I know but this will drag everything inside my library, polluting everything, and creates all kinds of things that I don't want, especially if I just need 1 or 2 piece of information, I just have to write this correctly and forget about it .

Comment: I don't see a problem. You usually don't name you local variables `CHAR_BIT` or `size_t`, so there isn't really any namespace pollution. And even if you find another way to determine the number of bits in a `char`, you'll have to define some identifier which will pollute the whole translation unit.

Comment: @mafso let's say that I don't like the solution, and as you said, the pollution is there, the fact that I don't use certain names doesn't mean that the namespace it's not being polluted . I'm ok now, I think I have enough to start coding something . If you'll post your comment about `__CHAR_BIT__` as an answer I'll accept it .

Answer (score 6):

> No sizeof please, my focus is on the bits and compile time .

Keep an open mind ;-P

```
#include <cstdint>

static_assert(sizeof(X) * CHAR_BIT == 32, "type X must be 32 bits in size");
```

Comment: yes but there is one little problem, the correct outcome basically depends on the correct value of `CHAR_BIT` which is a macro, that `static_assert` is basically relying on a macro which in turn is defined by some other `ifdef` voodoo magic; that's why I asked for some compiler builtin, I just want to feed the type and get the number of bits back . And the major point is that those `ifdef` need to have a good conditional associated with them, which is what I'm trying to find in the first place .

Comment: @user2485710 what do you mean some conditional and voodoo magic? It is simply preprocessor. You want something tested at compile time and don't wanna use preprocessor, then you are out of luck.

Comment: @texasbruce that's why I posed this question. And it's not me dodging the preprocessor, it's just that there is no standard way to detect the bitness and therefore no standard way to define `CHAR_BIT`, not even when I'm willing to use macros .

Comment: @user2485710: "ifdef voodoo magic" that the C++ Standard requires that the compilation environment provides correctly... you're worrying over nothing - builtin or macro: either way it's the compiler that's responsible, and with the macro it's Standard mandated.  There's nothing you need to do to make sure the macros are correct.  And while "macros may be evil", the *Standard*-mandated ones are well known and good libraries will be written not to screw with them or do potentially conflicting things....

Comment: @TonyD well I'm not just using a standard library ... but no matter what I'm doing now with C++, there is no way to tell the bitness or the bites in a byte without `CHAR_BIT` ? you are basically confirming that there isn't . That's why I'm putting the emphasis on the `builtins` of the compiler, because I already know this .

Comment: @user2485710: `CHAR_BIT` is the ***right***, ***proper*** way to get the number of bits.  You should not look further.  If you want to get twisted about this, you're more likely to end up with a bogus result.  That said, rici's suggestion of `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits` sounds better than compiler-specific features.

Comment: nope, it's even simpler, I'm just trying to find a function in the `gcc` and `clang` realm that will do this for me on any platform, without even using stupid preprocessor macros and text substitution . It's quite the opposite, I want to do less work an be more flexible and reliable with my implementation, but I guess I have to do things differently now compared to how I planned this altough I already knew that the standard relies heavily on `CHAR_BIT` being correct .

Comment: @user2485710 what this boils down to is that you want to be a perfectionist and avoid macros... my advice is simply get over it and do some coding.  C++ has an historic connection with C and has inherited this, it's been good enough for every C and C++ program ever written, and if you let yourself get hung up on things like this you'll never get anything useful done.  If that's unacceptable to you, propose a proper `const` value in some header to the C++ Committee for a future Standard, but looking for a compiler-specific alternative's unproductive.

Comment: @TonyD I'm not so extremist, but certainly a preprocessor macro doesn't look that good to me from both a functional point of view and aesthetically point of view.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. How to find the number of bits in a type without using the `CHAR_BIT` macro

If the type is a numeric type (like `int` and `char`), you can get the number of *significant* bits using `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits`, *assuming* that `T` is a binary type (that is, that `std::numeric_limits<T>::radix == 2`). Those are `constexpr` so they can be used in `static_assert`.

It is possible that the implementation is not capable of using all of the stored bits in some numeric type (other than `char`), in which case the number of significant digits may not relate to the physical size in bits. Also, the sign bit doesn't count, so you need to add `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed` to get the number of non-padding bits.

Since `char` types are not allowed to have padding and `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` are required to be exactly the same size, `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits` must be the number of bits in a `char`, otherwise known as the required macro `CHAR_BIT`. So you could use the two expressions interchangeably, and consequently the bit-size (physical, not meaningful) of any type `T` will be `sizeof(T)*std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits`.

I don't believe that the compiler itself needs to know what the bitsize of `char` is (although most compilers probably do). It does need to know what `sizeof(T)` is for every primitive type. There is no standard-mandated way of figuring out what the value of  `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits` is without including some header file.

#### 2. Why you shouldn't worry about it.

In a freestanding environment, `<numeric_limits>` is not required, but `<climits>` still is, so you can count on the `CHAR_BIT` even in a freestanding environment, while you can only count on `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::digits` in a hosted environment.

In other words, the compiler is obliged to have some way of providing the results of `#include <climits>`, because that header is required by the standard even in freestanding environments (that is, environments without a standard library or even operating system). That's the "built-in" you are looking for; even if you don't provide `<climits>` in your standard library implementation, and even if you don't have a standard library handy, the compiler must still arrange for the macro `CHAR_BIT` to be correctly defined following the occurrence of `#include <climits>`. How it does that is up to the compiler; `<climits>` does not have to be an actual file.

#### Notes

1. None of the above will work with C, but then neither will `static_assert` so I am assuming that tagging this question as C was an oversight. As @mafso points out in a comment, C11 does have a `static_assert` declaration, but it only works with C11-style constant expressions, not C++-style constant expressions. C++ constant expressions can use things like `constexpr` functions, which might be built-in. C constant expressions, on the other hands, can only involve integer literals. They are still useful (for non-purists) because macro expansion happens first, and the macro can expand to an integer literal (or even an expression involving several integer literals).

Comment: I appreciate that but this is even "worst", meaning that is using the standard library aside from the fact that the `CHAR_BIT` problem is still there, I just want the bits assuming that I know nothing about the platform and I don't trust evil macros because there is no standard way to **detect** bitness .

Comment: @user2485710: what is the `CHAR_BIT` problem exactly? And why is it still there if you use `numeric_limits`? Anyway, if neither this nor any other answer is good enough for you, then there is no compile-time solution, so the simple answer will be "no, no-one knows the way because it doesn't exist."

Comment: I'm implementing my own version of the std and I wasn't trying to find some clever way of doing this, but apparently everyone is happy with `CHAR_BIT` or the defaults of the given standard library .

Comment: I'm not questioning your techniques, I'm questioning the fact that in the end your solution is elegant, the macro based one is probably less elegant, but both are based on the same concept and the standard doesn't really provide any feature or keyword to check the bitness or the bits of char if we don't consider `CHAR_BIT`; and we don't consider `CHAR_BIT` because is something that is not a keyword of the language and it need an implementation in some header somewhere . Anyway, I see that there is no real option, thanks anyway .

Comment: Regarding the last note, C11 has introduced `_Static_assert` and a macro `static_assert` (expanding to the former) defined in `<assert.h>`...

Comment: if you want your own version of std, write a compiler yourself. gcc and clang aren't for custom standards

Answer (score 1):

According to [this document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html), the gnu compiler will define these macros for you:

```
__CHAR_BIT__      // bits

__SIZEOF_INT__    // bytes
__SIZEOF_LONG__
__SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__
etc...
```

You can define your own Bit macros from the Byte macros by just multiplying by 8.

Edit:  Since you apparently need to know the "word size" and consider pointers to be the same size as a "word", then use this:

```
__SIZEOF_POINTER__
```

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181709/gcc-extension-or-macro-to-check-the-bits-used-for-some-fundamental-types-at-comp#comment42851879_27181830 and this technique doesn't really work better than all the others .

Comment: I'm not sure what your objection is to these as they are all builtins.

Comment: well, try to determine the bitness or the "word size" of the underlying machine using just what you posted .

Comment: Can you define "word size"?  It's not a C concept.  Note in your question you asked for `unsigned int` and `char`.  You never mentioned "word size".

Comment: it's quite popular in the assembly community, it depends on your platform, for example, if you have a 32 bit OS running, the answer is 32, if you have a 64 bit os than 64. It also depends on the ABI used as you can imagine . I never mentioned but this is implicit since it's influencing the size of some fundamental types such as pointers for example .

Comment: But if you have a 64 bit os running, your program can still be built for 32 bit.  In that case, is the answer "32 bits" or "64 bits"?

Comment: do you know the differences in terms of ABI and the differences between `m32`, `mx32` or `m64` ? The answer to what I'm searching for it's not trivial if you have to start from nothing and rely on some macros .

Comment: I do know exactly what an ABI is.  But you never answered my question.   The reason I ask is that if you build for a 32-bit ABI and expect any kind of builtin to tell you that the size of a "word" is 64, then you won't find such a builtin.  But if expect the answer to be "32" in that case, then you can just use `__SIZEOF_POINTER__` as I have written in my edited answer (well that times 8).

Comment: I know that there isn't such thing, that's why I opened the question, everyone is focusing on macros but I was focusing on builtins too, anyway I think I know how to detect all the main bits of informations now given the comments I received .

Comment: if you're using mx32, the pointer is 32 bits but registers are all 64 bits then what is the word size in that case? To detect the "bitness" there are many other solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505582/determining-32-vs-64-bit-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706076/is-there-a-standard-way-to-determine-at-compile-time-if-system-is-32-or-64-bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152016/detecting-cpu-architecture-compile-time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272825/detecting-64bit-compile-in-c and so on