# Detect which target CPU a GCC configured for?

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting CPU architecture compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152016/detecting-cpu-architecture-compile-time)

Is there a define that GCC sets which tells which CPU (x86/amd64/ppc/etc) GCC is configured for?

So I can use it like:

```
#ifdef PPCARCH
  dosomething();
#endif
```

Comment: for compiled code or gcc itself?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Architectures - but I'm not sure how accurate is this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To detect the architecture at compile time in the source code use a predefined macro.

According to this [article](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/cpp/System_002dspecific-Predefined-Macros.html), it will always have a name in a form `_arch_` or `__arch__` where the arch is the name of the target architecture. To see what exactly defined, use the following command:

```
touch foo.h; cpp -dM foo.h; rm foo.h
```

It will print out all predefined macros.

To print out on the command line, try:

```
gcc -dumpmachine
```

It will show the target the GCC is is built for.

Comment: I think I was unclear, so I updated my question.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant I updated the answer to reflect your clarification