# Can _builtin_cpu_is be tricked into checking an array?

Tags: c++, gcc, built-in

I wanted to write a program displaying all CPU options on a current CPU.
Individual calls like this work:

```
if (__builtin_cpu_is("intel"))
```

Instead I would prefer to declare an array:

```
const char* cpuType[] = {
  "intel", "atom", "core2", "corei7", "nehalem",
  "westmere", "sandybridge", "amd", "amdfam10h", "barcelona", 
  "shanghai", "istanbul", "btver1", "amdfam15h",
  "bdver1", "bdver2", "bdver3", "bdver4", "btver2"
}
```

and in a loop check the same thing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(cputype)/sizeof(char*); i++)
  if (__builtin_cpu_is(cpuType[i])
```

gcc refuses, saying it has to be a constant string.

Is there any way to make this work aside from writing the code over and over?

Comment: Would POSH_CPU_STRING from http://stackoverflow.com/a/152032/257568 do?