# Conditional code depending on a gcc switch

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I'd like to cross-compile specific 32-bit and 64-bit code using an #if directive based on gcc switches.

Are there any macros set by GCC I could use instead of setting a macro using the -D switch?

Can I somehow pick up the switches used in the gcc command options to test them at the preprocessor stage?

So far I found out that -m64 defines on my 64-bit machine

```
   __x86_64__
```

whereas -m32 undefines

```
   __i386__ __i486__ __i586__ __i686__
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `INT_MAX` value from `<limits.h>`. This is C, so independent to compiler.

You can also check https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html to have some other predefined macros based on compiler options.

In general in recent time, it is recommend to write code portable, also with `if` that tests conditions that true only on specific architectures. Optimizer will remove unneeded branches.

Comment: How relevant this value when cross-compiling?

Comment: These values are target dependent (like types and binary code). The host do no matter. Headers are also target dependent, and if you look carefully, you see `#ifdef` with arch name in normal headers (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152016/detecting-cpu-architecture-compile-time). Note: on recent time, it is preferred not to do cross-compiling, but using an emulator and run gcc from there: there are a lot less problems with third party libraries (often their building scripts do not support cross-compiling).