# Macros for GCC/G++ to differentiate Linux and Mac OSX?

Tags: linux, macos, gcc, cross-platform, macros

Macros for GCC/G++ to differentiate Linux and Mac OSX?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The next time you want to check out pre-defined macros supported by GCC on a platform, run the preprocessor with the flag `-dM`. It'll list out all the predefined macros available on the system. For example:

```
$ touch dummy.hxx
$ cpp -dM ./dummy.hxx
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __FLT_MIN__ 1.17549435e-38F
#define __CHAR_BIT__ 8
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __DBL_DENORM_MIN__ 4.9406564584124654e-324
#define __FLT_EVAL_METHOD__ 0
#define __DBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-307)
#define __FINITE_MATH_ONLY__ 0
#define __SHRT_MAX__ 32767
#define __LDBL_MAX__ 1.18973149535723176502e+4932L
#define __UINTMAX_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __linux 1
#define __unix 1
#define __linux__ 1
...
```

Comment: @Viet: You're welcome... actually I ran into a similar conundrum as yours recently. I wanted to know if there was a pre-defined macro indicating the byte order of the machine. I hit upon this in some obscure documentation after hours and hours of searching!

Comment: For GCC on OS X, you can use `echo | g++ -dM -E -`

Comment: I like such kind of answer. It answers everything.

Comment: Note that there are different defines for C and C++; I had to add `-x c++` to the cpp command to get the values used for C++.

Comment: @Calmarius It's built into GCC. When it runs the preprocessor, it does so with these macros predefined. GCC exposes the -dM flag to list these macros.

Answer (score 13):

I'd be more inclined to test for feature availability than platform name. Try using [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/).

Otherwise, this is [a comprehensive list of platform defines](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/).

Also [check out this page](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/) for defines regarding compilers, libraries, architectures and devices.

Comment: Thanks but I avoid autoconf. I just want to use simple macros.

Comment: +1 for the "predef" link. There are much more defines one level higher in the wiki. Let me improve your reply.

Answer (score 9):

Detect OSX with the `__APPLE__` macro if you must. It's better to use `configure` to detect features if you can, but not everything works well that way.

Comment: Yeah, I chose this way in my code. I just have Linux & Apple so no issues. Thanks.

Comment: I find using compiler-defined macros like `__APPLE__` very useful because you can decouple the code from the build system, a lot of the time.  Then it makes your like a lot easier when porting to esoteric platforms like Android or Chrome NaCl, which don't necessarily play nice with `./configure` and friends

Comment: @Hans-Christoph: A good cross-compilation environment should help there.

Comment: The Android NDK is a good cross-compiler, and I do often use it to build projects with ./configure  But for many projects its just so much easier to write a quick Android.mk, and then you get a nicely integrated build system for free.

Answer (score 4):

I use `__MACH__` to test for Mac OS X - it's not 100% unique to Mac OS X (there may still be some old NeXT boxes out there !) but it's good enough for telling the difference between Mac and Linux.

Comment: __APPLE__ covers Mac OS X and iOS, so its a better bet than __MACH__ IMHO.  Its also more common from my experience

Comment: @Hans-ChristophSteiner APPLE is NOT defined on OS X it looks.

Comment: I guess @Hans means `__APPLE__` ? But even then I'm not sure it's 100% reliable?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I meant `__APPLE__` and `__MACH__`, looks like a wiki formatting error in my previous comment.