# Macro `__unix__` not defined in MacOS X

Tags: macos, unix, macros

I noticed that in MacOS X (Lion), the macro `__unix__` is not defined. 
Since MacOS has its roots in BSD UNIX, shouldn't that be the case?

Is it possible to let the compiler/preprocessor know that I want it to be considered a UNIX system?

Comment: You might have more luck with the POSIX macros instead http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Standards#Unix_Standards

Comment: See also: [Common macro to identify a UNIX derived system? (Linux, OSX, BSD, …)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917520)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [predefined macros site](http://predef.sf.net) suggests using:

```
#if defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix)
# define PREDEF_PLATFORM_UNIX
#endif
```

To distinguish UNIX systems. They also have warning notes about a number of compilers that don't set any of these. Depending on why you care about what the platform is you might be better off looking at configure time (in `configure.ac` or whatever build system you're using).

Comment: ./configure is not universal. In fact, it is mainly used in Unix and Unix-like platforms. Using it to detect "Unix" platforms does not sound good to me.

Comment: It is universal if you write you own. You can write your own, or equivalent component for almost any build system that matters. In CMake you write a  test in CMakeLists.txt, in autotools you write test in configure.ac, in ant you can do similar inside your XML. Scons has a similar concept too I believe, as does Python's distutils.

Comment: On Windows, you do not have Bash installed by default, and how can you ./configure? My other point was that ./configure is basically Unixy in the beginning: using it to detect Unix is like chasing the tail.

Comment: There are plenty of other tools that are cross platform that do have a configure stage even if they're not called ./configure. CMake being the obvious one, for this use case  was why I qualified that recommendation with "or whatever build system you're using"

Comment: According to the [site](http://web.archive.org/web/20160306052035/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system) linked in the answer by Yongwei Wu, Apple compilers don't define either  `unix`, `__unix` or `__unix__`, so I really don't understand how this was upvoted and set as correct answer by original poster.

Answer (score 20):

I think [this site](http://web.archive.org/web/20160306052035/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system) gives the most comprehensive answer.

In short, to include Apple platforms and common Unix platforms, you'll need:

```
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(__unix) || \
        (defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__))
...
#endif
```