# Common macro to identify a UNIX derived system? (Linux, OSX, BSD, ...)

Tags: c, macos, unix, macros, c-preprocessor

I wonder why on MacOSX the macro `__unix__` is not defined.

Isn't MacOSX a BSD UNIX derivative?

If I define the `__unix__` macro in my code, could I have some issues?

In general, when checking the current platform, I prefer to do something like:

```
#ifdef __unix__
...
#endif
```

instead of:

```
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__) || defined(BSD) ...
...
#endif
```

Could the best option be to define my own macro in a single place? E.g.:

```
#if defined(__unix__) || defined(__APPLE__) || defined(__linux__) || defined(BSD) ...
#define UNIX_
#endif
```

Comment: If you choose to do that, do not use double underscore in the name.

Comment: you'll get more eyes on your problem if you change one of your tags to 'c'. Good luck.

Comment: What sort of things would you surround with your `#ifdef __unix__` or `#ifdef UNIX_`? Perhaps you should be looking for better alternatives to those, like `__has_include()` or `__has_feature()` (depending on compiler support). Or autoconf.

Comment: See also: [Macro `__unix__` not defined in MacOS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063303)

Answer (score 4):

POSIX requires `_POSIX_VERSION` to be defined in `<unistd.h>` (also accessible via `sysconf(_SC_VERSION)`), so try that.

Comment: Ok, but before including <unistd.h> I have to check I am on a POSIX system, otherwise that file will not be available. And <unistd.h> should not be a small file to include...