# Is there a way to differentiate between Fedora and CentOS on CMake?

Tags: cmake

I need to build on CentOS but not Fedora. I've seen a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160335/os-specific-instructions-in-cmake-how-to) but that only checks to see if it's Windows vs Linux vs Other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does checking the contents of `/etc/os-release` work?
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html

You can just read in the file and it'll contain a line like `NAME="Ubuntu"`.
Use `file()` to parse it and grab the `NAME` field.

```
file(STRINGS /etc/os-release distro REGEX "^NAME=")
string(REGEX REPLACE "NAME=\"(.*)\"" "\\1" distro "${distro}")
file(STRINGS /etc/os-release disversion REGEX "^VERSION_ID=")
string(REGEX REPLACE "VERSION_ID=\"(.*)\"" "\\1" disversion "${disversion}")
message("found ${distro}.${disversion}")
```

outputs

```
found Ubuntu.20.04
```

Comment: That works! this is the above code with the conditional:

```file(STRINGS /etc/os-release distro REGEX "^NAME=")
string(REGEX REPLACE "NAME=\"(.*)\"" "\\1" distro "${distro}")
if( ${distro} STREQUAL "CentOS Linux" )
   ... BUILD INSTRUCTIONS ...
endif()```