# -dead_strip vs --gc-sections linker options

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to cross-build a piece of SW over Android and iOS using CMake. Android project uses GNU `ld`, while iOS uses `lld`. I need to add linker options for stripping dead code from linked libraries to both toolchains. I identified the way to achieve it adding on GNU `ld`, the `--gc-sections` linker options, while on `lld` adding the `-dead_strip` linker options. So, my question is:
Is there an alternative way to check cross-compiling platform, like below?

```
if(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL Android)
   target_link_options(GarminAis PRIVATE LINKER:--gc-sections)
elseif(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL APPLE)
   target_link_options(GarminAis PRIVATE LINKER:-dead_strip)
endif()
```

I would strongly prefer an unified approach.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Kudos for looking for a unified approach. In the meantime, you could make the distinction based on compiler used (`CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC`) instead of checking for Android as a platform. Not sure if that really improves things, just an idea.

Comment: @DevSolar good point, maybe checking CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_ID could be even better?

Comment: Jolly, that one had escaped my attention so far. Yes, that's even better (since the option isn't platform-dependent). As I can't find a property affecting that particular linker functionality, that's probably your best option at this point.

Comment: Seeing the answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9160449/3987854), it appears you could simplify your `APPLE` check.

Comment: To clarify, is it that you are currently writing these lines each in separate toolchain files, and that you would like a way to write them in one single file? It might also help readers if you explain why you want to do this: what do you not like about your current approach? What specifically would be better about what you are ideally looking for?

Comment: For the benefit of others reading this, iOS (and macOS) _do not_ use `lld`. They use the Darwin linker, which is a different program entirely.