# How to make CMakelists.txt to include some *.c and *.h files only for one OS?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, cmakelists-options

I want to include some *.c and *.h files only for Windows OS. But I can't find the way how to do it without creating another target, what entails a mistake

I want to do something like this:

```
add_executable(${TARGET}
     main.cpp
     mainwindow.cpp
     mainwindow.h
     mainwindow.ui
if (WIN32)
     test.c
     test.h
endif()
)
```

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Use a variable and set

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OS specific instructions in CMAKE: How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160335/os-specific-instructions-in-cmake-how-to)

Comment: BTW, I removed the `Qt` from the tags because I believe it is not important to the question or solution. It would be the same with or without  using the `Qt` framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modern CMake solution is to use `target_sources`.

```
# common sources
add_executable(${TARGET}
     main.cpp
     mainwindow.cpp
     mainwindow.h
     mainwindow.ui
)

# Stuff only for WIN32
if (WIN32)
    target_sources(${TARGET}
        PRIVATE test.c
        PUBLIC test.h
    )
endif()
```

This should make your `CMakeLists.txt` files easier to maintain than wrangling variables.

Comment: Thanks. I tend to still use many of the techniques I learned when I started using CMake in 2008. I will have to remember this the next time I use this technique which in my case I do from time to time want conditional inclusion of source files and factories.

Comment: @drescherjm - I was in the same boat until a few years ago.  It's a mind shift for sure, but I've found it far cleaner than the legacy style once I was willing to drink the kool-aid :)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using an `if` block, you can also constrain the sources with a [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:PLATFORM_ID):

```
add_executable(${TARGET} PUBLIC
   main.cpp
   mainwindow.cpp
   mainwindow.h
   mainwindow.ui
   $<$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>:
       test.c
       test.h
  >
)
```

This approach also works with the [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) command, if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a variable for your source file list and append to that variable the OS specific files similar to this:

```
set( MY_SOURCES 
     main.cpp
     mainwindow.cpp
     mainwindow.h
     mainwindow.ui
)

if (WIN32) 
SET( MY_SOURCES ${MY_SOURCES} 
     test.c
     test.h
)
endif()

add_executable(${TARGET} ${MY_SOURCES})
```