# Compile Unix code for WindowsCE

Tags: cygwin, windows-ce

I'm working on a library which was intended to use on Linux-only machines. So I choosed GNU autotools for build system and did everything with only Unix-like OSs in mind. After a while, we needed to port the library to Windows. Thanks to CygWin everything compiles and works fine. Now we need to provide the library for WindowsCE. Is this possible? I think CygWin does not support WinCE. Do I need to re-write the library for WinCE?

Comment: I don't see what is the situation, but probably you will need to make definitions for Windows and Linux. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive) it could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin does not support WinCE, so you will need to port your code to WinCE APIs.