# Fortran function that checks the type of operative system

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

Is there a function in Fortran that inquires the type of operative system? and gives this type as a string or similar? Basically I would like to use the function SYSTEM and run my program  both on linux and windows machines. My program employing the function SYSTEM works well on linux but now I want to do it general and run it also on windows. Lets say that this function I am looking for is called INQUIRE_SYSTEM. My program reads:

```
    USE IFPORT

    stringSYSTEM = INQUIRE_SYSTEM()

    if (TRIM(ADJUSTL(stringSYSTEM).eq.linux)) THEN ! linux systems
      I = SYSTEM("mv final.out restart.dat")
      If (I == -1) then
         errnum = ierrno( )
         print *, 'Error ', errnum
      end if
    else  !dos systems
      I = SYSTEM("rename final.out restart.dat")
      If (I == -1) then
      errnum = ierrno( )
      print *, 'Error ', errnum
    end if
```

thank you very much for any help.
A.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to check preprocessor macros.  Build up a list depending on what OSes you support.  See [How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive).

Many Fortran compilers will run the preprocessor when the filetype is upper-case: F90.  Or there is a compiler option.   Code example:

```
#ifdef __GFORTRAN__ 
    write (*, '( "gfortran" )' )
#endif
```

Why do you need to know the OS for a Fortran program?

Comment: I need to know in order to use the right command with the SYSTEM intrinsic function. See my example above. Here is the help for the function.http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/SYSTEM.html

Comment: SYSTEM is not the right choice for this - you can't retrieve the information. The use of conditional compilation, as M.S.B. suggests, is the most popular way to do what you're asking for.