# How can I check OS version (Windows) with preprocessor directives?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I would like to know if there is any chance to check which Windows version I really use. Something similar to: [How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive).

I tried code from MSDN:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724439(v=vs.85).aspx

But any of them gave me good results (for example: according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832(v=vs.85).aspx my code should print 5.1 when Im on Windows XP but it showed 5 ...)

Is there any reliable way (I would prefer preprocessor directives way) to find out which Windows I'm using?

My code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    OSVERSIONINFO osvi;
    BOOL bIsWindowsXPorLater;

    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);

    GetVersionEx(&osvi);

    // I HAD THIS, AND IT WAS WRONG! :<
    std::cout << osvi.dwMajorVersion << "\n";

    // CHANGED THE ABOVE LINE TO THE LINE BELOW AND IT IS OK NOW :D
    std::cout << osvi.dwMajorVersion << "." << osvi.dwMinorVersion << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That would be a bit hard to set up with preprocessor directives. There's a reason you have to tell the headers when you need a newer feature.

Comment: @chris: ok, and without preprocessor directives - is it possible?

Comment: The best I can say is the `GetVersion` stuff. I'm not sure why you'd get the wrong answer.

Comment: @chris: huh, checked it also on Windows 7 and get 6, instead of 6.1. Thats why I dont want to use it

Comment: @mazix how are you calling the GetVersionEx function?

Comment: You *did* set the `dwOSVersionInfoSize` member to `sizeof(<type>)`, right? I get 6.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: You're only outputting the major version part.

Comment: that explains everything ... :) cheers, guys!

Comment: Are you trying to get the Windows version that the program is *compiled* on or the version that it's *run* on?  You're asking about preprocessor directives, which implies the former, but why should you care where it's compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually getting the right result. But you are only printing the major version:

```
std::cout << osvi.dwMajorVersion << "\n";
```

Instead try using:

```
if (osvi.dwMinorVersion >= 1) {
     std::cout << osvi.dwMajorVersion << "." << osvi.dwMinorVersion << std::endl;
} else {
     std::cout << osvi.dwMajorVersion << std::endl;
}
```