# #ifdef _WIN32 not getting detected

Tags: c++, c++11

I can not get the #ifdef rule to work at least on windows (64 bit).
Compiler version is g++ 5.4.0
I have tried:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#ifdef _WIN64
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
```

I have compiled the following test with:
g++ main.cpp

Even with a simple code as this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "you are on...";

  #ifdef _WIN32
  std::cout << "Windows" << std::endl;
  #elif __linux__
  std::cout << "Linux" << std::endl;
  #endif

  return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
"you are on..."
```

...and nothing else gets couted out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive)

Comment: Are you *compiling* on Windows? Or just *running* on Windows?

Comment: Compiling on windows.

Comment: Run `echo | g++ -dM -E -` to see what defines you have.

Comment: G++... is that a MinGW or a Cygwin compiler? AFAICR, Cygwin doesn't set `_WIN32` because it isn't, it's a POSIX environment.

Comment: And.. Why do you expect anything to be printed out if you are on 64-bit Windows, and are only checking for 32-bit windows, and Linux?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: `_WIN32` should be defined for 32 **and** 64-bit Windows, as per documentation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - `_WIN32` is standard for both 32-bit and 64-bit windows.  It's a Windows thing.

Comment: @DevSolar Oh, I see. I wrote my comment before checking the full list of defined variables, present in the answer, of the linked question.. Thanks for correcting me :)

Comment: I have dumbed the list of defines as the Ville-Valtteri Tiittanen pointed out, but I can not sure what I should be looking for from that list.

Comment: Are you compiling on Windows through cygwin?

Comment: @Mikko-PenttiEinariEronen Do you have anything in there that looks like an operating system name? If not, it might be that G++ does not define that by default.

Comment: On Cygwin and/or the bash shell that was introduced for Win10, there really should be no expectation of any `WIN32` being defined.  Because these environments are trying to emulate Unix.  Not sure about MinGW, where it's possible to use the Windows SDK.

Comment: I'm using Cygwin's compiler on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Comment: Wokay. Answer below.

Comment: @selbie: MinGW GCC defines `_WIN32`, as it should. (Even when run on Linux as a cross-compiler.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> #ifdef _WIN32
> #ifdef _WIN64
> ```

These are pre-defined macros defined by the MSVC compiler. You appear to be using `g++` instead. That probably means either MinGW, or Cygwin.

---

[Here](http://beefchunk.com/documentation/lang/c/pre-defined-c/precomp.html) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/) are collections of macros pre-defined by several compilers.

> MinGW `__MINGW32__`
>
> Cygwin `__CYGWIN__`

---

If you prefer to not to build hefty ifdef - else trees, and scour the internet for macros defined by obscure compilers, and their different versions, I recommend to instead include a few headers from [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/predef.html). They have already done the hard part of the work. Although, note that `BOOST_OS_WINDOWS` is separate from `BOOST_OS_CYGWIN`.

Comment: I thank you all for the help and efford. This clears things up quite a bit for me.

Answer (score 4):

Use `__CYGWIN32__` to detect Windows when compiling g++ in cygwin. (This is defined in both 32 and 64 bit).

`_WIN32` &c. may not be defined in that case. It isn't for me.

(As also mentioned in a comment; using `echo | g++ -dM -E` to output the list of what is defined can be helpful.)

Answer (score -3):

yes, it is true that this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
```

sometimes doesn't work on Windows (!) In this case, use the following form instead:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
```

I was surprised but I have seen that problem and it helped me!