# How to use the --name argument to getopt?

Tags: command-line, cygwin, mingw, getopt

In the following example, I expected the error message to come from `xyz`, not from `getopt`. What am I doing wrong?

```
/tmp> getopt  --name xyz --options "xyz:" -- -x
 -x --
/tmp> getopt  --name xyz --options "xyz:" -- -x -z
getopt: option requires an argument -- z
 -x --
```

How do I make it say `xyz: option requires an argument -- z`; isn't that what `--name` is for?

**UPDATE**

Seems to be a bug. My getopt comes from cygwin

```
$ getopt --version
getopt from util-linux 2.25.2
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be bug in some versions of the program.

It works for me in  in Centos 7.3 and Fedora 19

```
[vps1 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
[vps1 ~]$ getopt  --name xyz --options "xyz:" -- -x -z
xyz: option requires an argument -- 'z'
 -x --
[vps1 ~]$  getopt -V
getopt from util-linux 2.23.2
```

But it doesn't in my MinGW shell (from Git for Windows)

```
$ getopt  --name xyz --options "xyz:" -- -x -z
getopt: option requires an argument -- z
-x --
$  getopt -V
getopt from util-linux 2.26.2
```

*Update*: It works also in 2.27.1 in Linux. And it doesn't work in (at least some version of) Cygwin. So the problem seems to be in the Windows ports (both Mingw and Cygwin, interestingly).

I'll throw a wild guess (not big probability of hitting the target): 
The `getopt` program, since [this commit](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux/+/30fbf2f679fb9072ea76034469ea400e33dffb62) tries to deal with some environnments (in particular, BSD;  *not* Linux) that have/use the  `getprogname/setprogname` to get/set the "current" program name (instead of relying on `argv[0]`).

```
#if defined (HAVE_SETPROGNAME) && !defined (__linux__)
        setprogname(name);
```

Now, let's imagine that

1. [Cygwin](http://www.sourceware.org/ml/newlib/2003/msg00624.html) and MinGW/Msis both support those functions.
2. However, they lack the `HAVE_SETPROGNAME` define
3. Further, their `getopt` functions (mind you, not the program), just like the BSD version, use `getprogname` instead of `argv[0]`

In that case, the problem would be explained. However, I'm skeptical - of point 3 especially.

Comment: I have `getopt from util-linux 2.25.2` from cygwin. Either a recent bug or windows related?

Comment: Perhaps adding the tags cygwin and mingw to attract some developers.... ?

Comment: @rudimeier I don't think that MinGW defines `__linux__` See eg http://stackoverflow.com/a/647640/277304

Comment: Now I could test it on Cygwin. The commit you are mentioning really fixes the behavior for non-linux, including windows. But you need util-linux >= 2.28 to get it. In case you can't update you may workaround using shell tricks: `bash -c 'exec -a "XYZ" getopt  --name xyz --options "xyz:" -- -x -z'`. Note that the fixed getopt version would override this trick again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug (or just a non-portability issue) which is already fixed in `util-linux 2.28`, by [commit 30fbf2f6](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/commit/30fbf2f679fb9072ea76034469ea400e33dffb62). Before this fix it worked only on Linux, OSX and a few BSD flavors but not on WIN32 or GNU-Hurd for example.

If you can't upgrade `util-linux` (might be difficult to build on windows), then you could use this shell workaround:

```
bash -c 'exec -a "XYZ" getopt --options "xyz:" -- -x -z'
```

Note that still using the `--name` option would override this trick again once if getopt will be updated one day.

Of course you could also simply copy/link/rename the `getopt` program to whatever name you want.