# How to write to a NULL device/file on Windows (10) so I can **not** read back what was written?

Tags: windows, dev-null

Windows does have a concept for [null devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/313111/1672565), [here](https://superuser.com/q/134214/177999) or [here](https://serverfault.com/q/132963/171146) for example. All examples that I can find are about redirecting streams.

While porting a script from Linux to Windows, I came across something odd: If `nul` is opened like a file, I an write to it, close it, re-open it and read the data back. Sometimes. Checking the working directory, I can see a file named `nul` being created and growing as I write data to it. Ironically, I can not delete it from the explorer, only from the command line.

Windows 10 comes with its a native implementation of OpenSSH nowadays. I wanted to use an old trick: When it is looking for the `known_hosts` file, I want to point it to a null device instead. On Linux, this looks as follows: `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null user@host`. On Windows, I tested it as follows: `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=nul user@host`. I got a file named `nul` containing the hosts. I also tried `NUL`, `null` and `NULL` with the same result. Trying to point to `\Device\Null` or `/Device/Null` causes `ssh` to complain that it can not find/open those files.

How do I correctly use and/or point to the null device on Windows (10)?

Comment: are you using powershell or cmd

Comment: Both cmd and Python scripts (with sub-processes). Result is always the same. Have not tried Powershell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45391321/449722

Comment: try powershell, `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=$null user@host`

Comment: @g01d The NUL followed by a colon (`NUL:`) does not work: I get a file with some unicode character instead of a colon. This is bizarre.

Comment: @KetZoomer While I use cmd for testing, for production I am starting my processes independent of any shell, i.e. [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) with `shell = False`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JS crowd has a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11053977/1672565): I need to point to `\\.\NUL`. This is the actual name or path of the null device, apparently.

Comment: That actually makes sense, being a full UNC path. Good find. https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/unc

Answer (score 3):

What I'm doing is create a file `C:\Users\myself\.ssh\config` (just like on Linux), with this:

```
# Don't save local computers to known_hosts
Host localhost 127.?*.?*.?* *.local 10.?*.?*.?* 192.168.?*.?* 172.16.?*.?* 172.17.?*.?* 172.18.?*.?* 172.19.?*.?* 172.2?.?* 172.30.?*.?* 172.31.?*.?*
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile=\\.\NUL
```

This matches most IPv4 thingies/whatever that are considered [private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). Do this at home, but not in your company network though - because of reasons.