# Macro for finding OS in SWIG interface file

Tags: c++, swig

Is there a way to find the Operating system in SWIG interface file.
There are macros like SWIGWIN which can be used for windows.
Is there any macro for differentiating LINUX and CYGWIN.

Comment: You should be able to use `#ifdef`s like in normal C(++), see http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Preprocessor.html#Preprocessor_condition_compilation. So this becomes a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive.

Comment: Hi I know that these macros exist but which macro will help me to differentiate between cygwin and linux environments

Comment: Have you tried to search the page I linked for `cygwin`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040445/711006