# POSIX C wrapper for win32, linux, mac

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, posix

Can someone suggest a lightweight C library/header wrapper for POSIX functions that can be used cross-platform?

For example, it could be as simple as mapping `open` and `close` which are `_open` and `_close` in win32. Then there are functions with slightly more differences. I am aware of `common c++`, `boost` and `posixcpp`, but they are overkill for the need.

I was considering writing it myself, but just checking if someone already did it rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Posix is cross-platform. The problem is Windows. Microsoft supported Posix as an optional subsystem in some versions of the operating system, and stopped supporting Poxis in other versions of the operating system.

Comment: I hope that on Windows `open()` and `close()` are mapped to `_open()` and `_close()` resp. instead of the other way around.

Comment: Just target WSL if using Windows.

Comment: @Shawn that's only possible if you're only targeting developers who use WSL (which is just a tiny part of the whole). \@yumoji C or C++? They're very different. In C++17 just use `std::filesystem` for portability

Comment: *overkill for the need*? What do you mean? Just use the part of them you need... Portability is not a simple problem as to substitute identifiers, nor creating simple stubs... If you use C, then C I/Os are portable (fopen/fclose). If you need POSIX functions (open/close) then you ned to have a posix subsystem on the host.

Answer (score 1):

If it's only one or two functions, you could detect windows at compile time: [How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive)

You could, for instance, test for windows, and create a macro that maps `open` to `_open` if you're compiling for windows.

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
#define open _open
#endif
```