# Need a function to get windows OS name and version

Tags: c++, windows

There are tons of questions regarding this issue on stack overflow, still couldn't find a simple function to get `windows` name along with its `version`.

This is what I need

```
std::string OS = getOsName();
std::cout << OS << std::endl;
```

output:

```
Windows 10.0
```

I'm not interested in the build version or minor versions at all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive

Comment: Perhaps the example code on this page will help:  https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/cppmfc/get-windows-version-from-registry.html

Comment: @kiner_shah: Isn't that QA about determining what kind and version of target OS a programed is currently being compiled for. That's not the same as figuring out the system environment at runtime.

Comment: @datenwolf, ohh yeah, you are right, my bad!