# C++20 conditional import statements

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

There's a way to conditionaly use import statements with the C++20 modules feature?

// Pseudocode

```
IF OS == WINDOWS:

import std.io;

ELSE:

import <iostream>;
```

Comment: You mean... like macros? Yes, they aren't gone. Conditional compilation is still their domain.

Comment: [How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive)

Comment: This isn't even correct, it's not an OS-specific consequence whether or not you have `std.io` to import.

Comment: @Blindy compiler specific, but I was assuming some common sense for the reader that when `std.io` appers, assuming Windows + MSVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use macros, just like you would for most other conditional compilation operations. And yes, this means that modules have to be built differently for different command line options. But that was always going to be the case.

Also FYI: `std.io` is a thing provided by MSVC, *not* Windows. And you should avoid using it due to its non-standard (and likely not-going-to-be-standard) status. If you must use one of MSVC's standard library modules, use `import std;`.

Comment: You are right as always @NicolBolas. The fact it's that I have a Clang C++20 project, that usually I build in Unix systems. Using the Clang common command line options, I build without issues using import statements instead include directives. But sometimes I am working on Windows, and don't want to switch back to Arch, so I code, but using #include directives, I always get `error: reference to 'type_info' is ambiguous
    const type_info& _Target_type() const noexcept override {...` and if I use import statements, I get `cannot be imported because it is not known to be a header unit`

Comment: So I was wondering if I can use a preprocessor directive to replace them, but #include directives wasn't working at this moment for me. 
By the way, build process is completly automated with this tool `https://github.com/Pyzyryab/Zork`, so I must include different options to get those header working correctly under Windows, but I am still trying the correct Clang cmd options to make it work (no success up until this point)