# Preprocessor macro to check for x64 platform with ONE condition?

Tags: c-preprocessor, visual-studio-2022, platform, conditional-compilation, visual-c++-2022

In a C project, at some places, I'd like to compile different code, depending on whether or not the compilation happens for `x64`. Of course, CPP macros are the route to go.

However, on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170) (which should be the authoritative reference), there is no predefined macro just for x64.

Out of curiosity, did I miss something?

I am aware that I easily can solve the actual problem:

**First,** according to the reference above, if I would like to stick with predefined macros, I could do something like that:

```c
#if defined (_M_AMD64) && (_M_AMD64 == 100) && !defined (_M_ARM64EC)
....
#endif
```

The first two conditions make sure we compile for `x64` or `arm64ec`, the third condition makes sure we do not compile for `arm64ec`, which together should make sure we compile for `x64`.

**Second,** I could define my own macro in the project settings for x64 configurations and use that instead of a predefined one:

```c
#ifdef MY_OWN_X64_FLAG
...
#endif
```

While they solve the problem, both methods are not intuitive and elegant. Is there really no predefined macro that we can use to test for `x64` only with one simple `#ifdef`?

Comment: The "obvious" `_M_X64` suffers from the same braindamage as `_M_AMD64`. You have to wonder what went wrong. It appears the ARM64 code was copied straight from the AMD64 code, and that explains why there is no answer.

Comment: there's no simpler ways than to use [boost platform predefs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52992284/995714)

Comment: [*"When you compile your code as ARM64EC, the architecture preprocessor symbols will say that you are compiling for x86-64. There’s a reason for this. See the linked article for the answer"*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220830-00/?p=107069)

Answer (score 0):

> did I miss something?

No.

> Is there really no predefined macro that we can use to test for x64 only with one simple #ifdef?

Yes, according to your own research and to the linked documentation, there is really no predefined macro to test for x86_64 with one simple #ifdef *on that compiler*.