# How to fix a compiler error that should be excluded by a preprocessor directive between #ifdef?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a program that compiles on both MacOS and Linux. In my makefile, I define a variable:

```Makefile
# MAC
ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
OS          = APPLE
    
#LINUX
else
OS          = LINUX
endif
    
INCLUDES    = -Iincludes -Ilibft -I$(MLX_DIR) -D$(OS)
```

Leading to the following compilation:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -Iincludes -Ilibft -I./minilibx_mms -DAPPLE -c srcs/parser/parser.c -o objs/parser/parser.o
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -Iincludes -Ilibft -I./minilibx_mms -DAPPLE -c srcs/terminate/gameover_sys.c -o objs/terminate/gameover_sys.o
```

As you can see, I am passing `APPLE` as a macro so when I call this function:

```
    if (cub->mlx)
    {
        #ifdef LINUX
        mlx_destroy_display(cub->mlx);
        #endif
        free(cub->mlx);
    }
```

Everything between the `#ifdef` and `#endif` should be removed before compilation, right? But alas, I am getting this error from the compiler:

```
Call to undeclared function 'mlx_destroy_display'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations clang(-Wimplicit-function-declaration)
```

The function only exists in the Linux implementation of the library. Where is my understanding of preprocessor directives incorrect? To my understanding the whole `#ifdef LINUX` part should be removed when the `LINUX` macro is not present.

Comment: Maybe one of your included headers defines that macro?

Comment: Hi Gerhardh!

I do notice now in a header I have this:

/* OS CHECK */
# ifdef APPLE
#  define LINUX 0
#  define ESC_KEY 53

However, I thought defining it to 0 would mean it is undefined. Apparently that is not the case?

Comment: @Hendrik No. Definining it t`o` 0 means it is **defined** for the purposes of `#ifdef/#ifndef/#if defined(Macro)` checks. But if you do `#if LINUX` instead, then both an undefined and a 0-defined LINUX will cause that `#if` branch to be deleted. (That's why I personally prefer `#if` over `#ifdef`).

Comment: Thanks all. You are right, a simple #if LINUX instead of #ifndef LINUX sufficed. This seems so obvious now in hindsight.

Comment: @Hendrik It might not be super obvious. The preprocessor replaces undefined tokens with 0 in its `#if` conditionals. So `#if some_undefined+3 == 3` is a taken branch. That's why sometimes you see casts like `((int)+OTHER_MACRO)` macro definitions so that those macros are also usable in `#if` conditionals where they become `((0)+something)`.

Comment: You must distinguish using `#ifdef XY` from `#if XY`. They behave different if you define to 0.

Answer (score 2):

> How to fix a compiler error that should be excluded by a preprocessor directive between #ifdef?

`LINUX` is very simple common name, and standard headers or other projects may already define it. Use a unique prefix of macros for your project.

```
# Makefile
ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
OS = APPLE
else
OS = LINUX
endif
CFLAGS = -Iincludes -Ilibft -I$(MLX_DIR) -DYOUR_LIBRARY_NAME_OS_$(OS)

# C file
#ifdef YOUR_LIBRARY_NAME_OS_LINUX
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

Check for a **reserved** symbol such as `__linux__` or `__MACH__` instead of defining your own.

From [GCC's online predefined macros documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-specific-Predefined-Macros.html#System-specific-Predefined-Macros) (N.B. the bolded portions):

> The C standard requires that all system-specific macros be part of the
> *reserved namespace*. All names which begin with two underscores, or an underscore and a capital letter, are reserved for the compiler and
> library to use as they wish. However, historically system-specific
> macros have had names with no special prefix; for instance, it is
> common to find `unix` defined on Unix systems. For all such macros, GCC
> provides a parallel macro with two underscores added at the beginning
> and the end. If `unix` is defined, `__unix__` will be defined too. There
> will never be more than two underscores; the parallel of `_mips` is
> `__mips__`.
>
> When the `-ansi` option, or any `-std` option that requests strict
> conformance, is given to the compiler, **all the system-specific
> predefined macros outside the reserved namespace are suppressed**. The
> parallel macros, inside the reserved namespace, remain defined.
>
> **We are slowly phasing out all predefined macros which are outside the
> reserved namespace**. ...

For example:

```
$ echo | gcc -dM -E - | grep -i linux
#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
#define linux 1
```

versus with `-std=c11`:

```
$ echo | gcc -std=c11 -dM -E -  | grep -i linux
#define __linux 1
#define __linux__ 1
#define __gnu_linux__ 1
```

By using a reserved symbol, you also have protection from name collisions with third-party headers.

Also, see [**How do I check OS with a preprocessor directive?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142508/how-do-i-check-os-with-a-preprocessor-directive)